# How to find 3d point with minimum sum of euclidean distances to all given segments?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, gradient-descent

N segments in 3d space are given. Segment is represented by 2 points. The problem is to find the point with minimal possible sum of distances to all segments.

Comment: I once had this question in a programming contest long time ago and succeeded quickly using dowhnhill simplex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method), because it is pretty easy to implement and performance was okay too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the segments be p<sub>1</sub> q<sub>1</sub>, …, p<sub>n</sub> q<sub>n</sub>. We formulate an optimization problem:

> minimize ∑<sub>i</sub> ‖x − ((1 − y<sub>i</sub>) p<sub>i</sub> + y<sub>i</sub> q<sub>i</sub>)‖
> subject to
> x ∈ ³
> ∀i, y<sub>i</sub> ∈ [0, 1]

The variable x is the point we’re looking for. The variables y<sub>i</sub> take advantage that we’re trying to minimize a minimum (minimum distance to x) and are used to form the convex combination in the objective.

This is a convex problem, so either cvxpy or scipy.optimize should be able to handle it nicely.